# pass hidden variable via header with php

Tags: php, http-headers, parameter-passing

you know that i can manipulate the headers in php like this:

```
header("Content-Type: ..."); 
header('Content-Description: ...');
```

I want to use that to send a variable which is hidden for the user.

so three questions occured:

1. Can I change add a field say: `additional-content-information`
   and set it to `Hello
   world` or will it fail?
2. Or can I change i.e.
   `content-description` to a desired
   value like `hello World`?
3. How can I get all these informations
   which I set with the `header()`
   function at the target page?

As far I tried out to change the values, and also to add some. But I didn't get any errors. But as long as i cannot access the current header informations I cannot see if it failed or not.

An example of my current code:

```
$var2pass = $_GET['var'];

header( "refresh:2;url=target.php", false );
header('Content-Description: '.$var2pass);
header('Additional-Content-Information: '.$var2pass);
```

the redirect works and I get a site displayed ...

**UPDATE**

well .. I cannot use cookies and session because the information depends on the site where you come from. and the user might have more than one tab or window opened where it should be the same session. Createing an entry for every page will lead to pass the identifier which I also don't want. I need a friendly url

Comment: If you want to keep something hidden from the user — **don't send it to their browser**.

Comment: why not just use $_REQUEST[]; and send it through the URL for example; ..index.php?msg="Hello+World"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use cookies. Use [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for setting cookie on server (must be done before anything is printed/echoed), `$_COOKIE` for reading them on server, `document.cookie` for reading and writing them in browser (javascript). Cookies are like "variables" that are generally invisible to user and that are accessible between requests, i.e., you can set it in one page request and read in another.

That being said, keep in mind that cookies are not *safe*, i.e., although most users won't see them, they are in no way secure against reading and/or writing them by user. If you need secure variables that are inaccessible by user, consider using sessions - [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and `$_SESSION`.

Comment: But remember, that they has some limitations -- size of data and also could be disabled.

Comment: well .. I cannot use cookies and session because the information depends on the site where you come from. and the user might have more than one tab or window opened where it should be the same session.
Createing an entry for every page will lead to pass the identifier which I also don't want. I need I friendly url

Answer (score 1):

You could send them in this way, but it will be impossible to read them by browser.
But you can send them as some json object in the HTML of the generated page.
Just specify more carefully, what is "hidden for the user."